# How to embed video Files in WPF C# and change sources

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on an interactive app that shows different video's based on different stages, I am using C# and WPF and I am trying to use a MediaElement and change it source but it only let me play 1 video file and will not change to the next video, it will keep playing the same file over and over again, I just can't seem to understand why is this happening, I also couldn't find a solution to this online, I have embedded both video files "Stage8.mp4" and "Stage12.mp4" in my solution explorer, Both video files are set to copy if newer and content, also I don't think there is something wrong in the path because if I switch between them it will play the correct file, it just won't change the source in real time.
here are my codes:

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace WPF_Tester
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }



    string NameChecker;
    byte stage = 0;

    private void BTN1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NameChecker = "Name: " + TXT1.Text + " Last: " + TXT2.Text;

        if (testlistview.Items.Contains(NameChecker))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The name already exists.");
        }
        else
        {
            testlistview.Items.Add(NameChecker);
        }
        
        if (stage == 0)
        {
            TestElement.Source = new Uri("Stage12.mp4", UriKind.Relative);
            TestElement.Play();
            stage = 1;
        }
        if (stage == 1)
        {
            TestElement.Source = new Uri("Stage8.mp4", UriKind.Relative);
            TestElement.Play();
            stage = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

}

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_Tester.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_Tester"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Name:" FontSize="20" Margin="20,40,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>
    <TextBox x:Name="TXT1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18" Margin="80,40,0,0" MinWidth="30"></TextBox>
    <TextBlock Text="Last Name:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="20" Margin="20,80,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>
    <TextBox x:Name="TXT2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18" Margin="120,80,0,0" MinWidth="30"></TextBox>
    <Button x:Name="BTN1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="Add Name" FontSize="20" Margin="20,180,0,0" Click="BTN1_Click"></Button>
    <!-- here we set controls for the second column.-->
    <ListView x:Name="testlistview" Grid.Column="1" Margin="20,40,20,20" FontSize="20" ></ListView>
    <MediaElement Name="TestElement" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,200,20,0" UnloadedBehavior="Manual" Source="/Stage12.mp4" LoadedBehavior="Play"></MediaElement>
</Grid>
```

Thanks in advance and have a great day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an else missing. Your second if statement always resets the file to the first. Adding `else` should implement the desired toggling.

```
    if (stage == 0)
    {
        TestElement.Source = new Uri("Stage12.mp4", UriKind.Relative);
        TestElement.Play();
        stage = 1;
    }
    //we need an else here, otherwise source is always "Stage12.mp4
    else if (stage == 1)
    {
        TestElement.Source = new Uri("Stage8.mp4", UriKind.Relative);
        TestElement.Play();
        stage = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you your solution worked, how could I forget such a simple thing.